# arithmetic expression evaluates to zero when with parenthesis

Tags: android, arithmetic-expressions

I have the above code

```
private float farenaitCelsiusMath(float f) {

        float result;
        result = (f-1)*(2/3);
        return result;
    }
```

when i run the app on the emulator it evaluates to 0 whatever value i give to f.

But when the third line to `result = (f-1)*2/3;` it evaluates correctly.

Why does that happens? Is there sth i should know about arithmetic expressions in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `(2/3)` is INTEGER division, which evaluates to 0 since integer division truncates.

- `(f-1)` is FLOAT since `f` is FLOAT
- `(2/3)` is INTEGER value 0 since integer division truncates
- `(f-1)*(2/3)` is FLOAT since `(f-1)` is FLOAT, and value 0 because anything times 0 is 0.

When it's `(f-1)*2/3` then it evaluates as

- `(f-1)` is FLOAT since `f` is FLOAT;
- `(f-1)*2` is FLOAT since (`f-1)` is FLOAT
- `(f-1)*2/3` is FLOAT since `(f-1)*2` is FLOAT

To get what you expect, make it `(2./3)` or `(2/3.)` -- both are promoted to FLOAT because of the decimal point-- or even better make it explicit with a cast `((float)2/(float)3)`.  This doesn't cost anything at run time, it's all done by the compiler.

Comment: dont forget to mention why it works when it isnt in parens. The integers get converted to floats before the multiplication and division in the second version.

Comment: yes that make sense. I didn't know about that. So when they are inside parens they stay integer and the result is also integer which means 0.  Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Charlie Martin great. Thank you. I get it now. So the best way is to write it (f-1)*(2.0/3.0)

Comment: Yeah, I was expanding that as you commented, Scott.  @miako, it's not really the parens, it's evaluation order -- plus the rule that arithmetic operation promote to the "bigger" type.  Floats are higher, so any float time an integer becomes a float.  In your example, (2/3) has been converted to 0 by integer division. Now, in other languages, the result of 2/3 would be a floating point type, the value would be 0.6666666 and change, and you'd get what you expect.

Comment: @CharlieMartin  So i have to read about the operators order. It's important

Comment: @miako, it is, but this is a simple case.  What fooled you was that Java integer division returns an integer, not a float.